# How do I create a following system in django?

Tags: python, django

I needed a following system, so I tried to rely on already written codes.
The views weren't there and I tried to write them alone, but I couldn't.
I am new to Django and sorry I don't know English well.
Thanks in advance!

error

ValueError at /accounts/segui/2/1/ <Follower: Follower object (None)> instance isn't saved. Use bulk=False or save the object first

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Follower(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='following')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='followers')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('follower', 'following')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s segue %s' % (self.follower, self.following)
```

views.py

```
def AddFollowerView(request, pk, id):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        userFollow = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        follower= Follower()
        follower.objects.bulk_create([
            follower(follower=user, following=userFollow),
        ])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/stories/')

def RemoveFollowerView(request, pk, id):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        userFollow = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        user.following.remove(Follower(following=userFollow))
        user.following.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/stories/')
```

urls.py

```
path('follow/<int:pk>/<int:id>/', AddFollowerView, name="add-follower"),
path('not-follow/<int:pk>/<int:id>/', RemoveFollowerView, name="remove-follower"),
```

Sorry if this question has been asked several times, but I have not been able to understand how to solve it.

Comment: looks like you need brackets to right way initiate the model instance `follower = Follower()`

Comment: It gives me the following error AttributeError at /accounts/follow/2/1/

Manager isn't accessible via Follower instances

Comment: The problem might be this `user.following.add(Follower(following=userFollow))`. You can't add a Follower to the followings of `user` because that instance isn't saved in the DB yet and so it's not possible to relate it to `user`

Comment: So what should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling a manager method on a single Model instance, but you can only call manager methods on a queryset or the un-instantiated class (sorry bad explanation, feel free to improve). That would explain the error `AttributeError at /accounts/follow/2/1/ Manager isn't accessible via Follower instances`

So practically, remove these lines:

```
follower = Follower()
follower.objects.bulk_create([follower(follower=user, following=userFollow)])
```

And replace by:

```
Follower.objects.create(follower=user, following=userFollow)
```

Or:

```
follower_object = Follower(follower=user, following=userFollow)
follower_object.save()
```